# Can't use variable as path - is not defined at <top-level>,

Tags: bash, jq

Here bash script using jq to parse json

```
ruleTypes=( 
       ["Bugs"]=0 
       ["Vulnerabilities"]=0 
       ["CodeSmells"]=0
       ["SecurityHotspots"]=0        
     )

for rulesTypeKey in "${!ruleTypes[@]}"; do
  #echo "rules types $rulesTypeKey = ${ruleTypes[$rulesTypeKey]}"
  for currentActivation in ${ACTIVATION_ARRAY[@]}; do
      rulesResponse=$(curl -s -XGET "$RULES_REQUEST_URL_PREFIX&activation=$currentActivation&types=$rulesTypeKey&p=1&ps=1")
      totalRules=$(jq -r '.total' <<< "$rulesResponse")
      ruleTypes[$rulesTypeKey]=$totalRules
      jq --argjson totalArg "$totalRules" '.rules.active.Bugs = $totalArg ' <<<$RULES_REPORT_INIT_JSON >$FILE_REPORT_RULES      
  done
done
```

This work fine. Nice.

Now I want to use variable **$path** for path. I try this:

```
ruleTypes=( 
       ["Bugs"]=0 
       ["Vulnerabilities"]=0 
       ["CodeSmells"]=0
       ["SecurityHotspots"]=0        
     )

for rulesTypeKey in "${!ruleTypes[@]}"; do
  #echo "rules types $rulesTypeKey = ${ruleTypes[$rulesTypeKey]}"
  for currentActivation in ${ACTIVATION_ARRAY[@]}; do
      rulesResponse=$(curl -s -XGET "$RULES_REQUEST_URL_PREFIX&activation=$currentActivation&types=$rulesTypeKey&p=1&ps=1")
      totalRules=$(jq -r '.total' <<< "$rulesResponse")
      ruleTypes[$rulesTypeKey]=$totalRules
      path=".rules.active.$rulesTypeKey"
      jq --argjson totalArg "$totalRules" '$path = $totalArg ' <<<$RULES_REPORT_INIT_JSON >$FILE_REPORT_RULES      
  done
done
```

But I get error:

```
jq: error: $path is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
$path = $totalArg 
jq: 1 compile error
```

P.S

I try this (double quotes):

```
jq --argjson totalArg "$totalRules" "$path = $totalArg" <<<$RULES_REPORT_INIT_JSON >$FILE_REPORT_RULES .
```

But get error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
```

Comment: You define `totalArg` as arg, not `path`.

Comment: Regarding the error message: The assignment operator `=` is to replace (a part of) a JSON document (an array item, for instance) with a given value. You cannot assign a value to a variable as you are trying to do with `$path = $totalArg`. To have a new variable `$path` with that value, use `$totalArg as $path`.

Comment: One side note (besides my answer): In case you ever think that your script one day should be ported to zsh, I suggest not to name a variable `path`, which is reserved in zsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$totalRules` is supposed to be a number you should drop the `-r` option when reading it

```sh
totalRules=$(jq '.total' <<< "$rulesResponse")
```

and use `--argjson` when setting it

```sh
jq --arg key "$rulesTypeKey" --argjson total "$totalRules" \
  '.rules.active[$key] = $total'
```

If `$totalRules` may also produce raw text (in edge cases, for instance), and you want to store that value as string, leave the `-r` option when reading it, and use `--arg` when setting it:

```sh
jq --arg key "$rulesTypeKey" --arg total "$totalRules" \
  '.rules.active[$key] = $total'
```

Comment: PS: Never try to inject shell variables into the jq filter with the help of double quotes as in `jq "… ${shellvar} …"`.

Answer (score 0):

You have single quotes around your argument:

```
'$path = $totalArg '
```

Therefore variables won't be expanded by the shell, and `jq` sees the literal string `$path`, which is undefined. If you had used double quotes, both `path` and `totalArg` would be expanded.

Comment: I try this: jq --argjson totalArg "$totalRules" "$path = $totalArg"  <<<$RULES_REPORT_INIT_JSON >$FILE_REPORT_RULES

.   But get error: jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:

Comment: @Alexei : Don't put multi-line code into a comment.  You can amend your question (there is a small _Edit_ link under your question). However, if you are facing a new problem, it makes more sense to ask a new question.